# Included layout children changing when rotated

Tags: java, android, xml, rotation, view

I've recently started porting my app over to Android from iOS and I am having a bit of a struggle.
What I am trying to do is display some data in a bunch of key-value type pair things.
I'm using included views to save code, here is my code:
**detail_verb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/englishOutlet"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            <include android:id="@+id/jeOutlet" layout="@layout/detail_verb_conjugation" />
            <include android:id="@+id/tuOutlet" layout="@layout/detail_verb_conjugation" />
            <include android:id="@+id/ilOutlet" layout="@layout/detail_verb_conjugation" />
            <include android:id="@+id/nousOutlet" layout="@layout/detail_verb_conjugation" />
            <include android:id="@+id/vousOutlet" layout="@layout/detail_verb_conjugation" />
            <include android:id="@+id/ilsOutlet" layout="@layout/detail_verb_conjugation" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**detail_verb_conjugation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/pp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/con"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="10dp" />
    <View 
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/con" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**VerbDetail.java**

```
package co.uk.iVerbs.iverbsfrench;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;

public class VerbDetail extends Activity {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.detail_verb);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final DataModel verb = intent.getParcelableExtra("verb");
        setTitle(verb.infinitive);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.englishOutlet);
        textView.setText(verb.english);

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.jeOutlet);
        textView = (TextView)jeOutlet.findViewById(R.id.pp);
        textView.setText("Je");
        textView = (TextView)jeOutlet.findViewById(R.id.con);
        textView.setText(verb.je);
        Log.d("asf", jeOutlet.toString());

        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tuOutlet);
        textView = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.pp);
        textView.setText("Tu");
        textView = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.con);
        textView.setText(verb.tu);

        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ilOutlet);
        textView = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.pp);
        textView.setText("Il/Elle");
        textView = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.con);
        textView.setText(verb.il);

        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.nousOutlet);
        textView = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.pp);
        textView.setText("Nous");
        textView = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.con);
        textView.setText(verb.nous);

        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.vousOutlet);
        textView = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.pp);
        textView.setText("Vous");
        textView = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.con);
        textView.setText(verb.vous);

        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ilsOutlet);
        textView = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.pp);
        textView.setText("Ils/Elles");
        textView = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.con);
        textView.setText(verb.ils);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Whenever I rotate the detail view, all the rows change to "Ils/Elles" and the respective value for that field for some reason. This is the last row, can anybody help?

[image: How it should be]
[image: How it ends up when rotated :/]

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem with the same symptom as you and after many experiments discovered that it is due to

```
android:textIsSelectable
```

attribute. If you remove it from xml, rotation will start to work ok. This should be some framework bug. I am going to file an issue for that.